# How to reinitialize express session within request logic?

Tags: node.js, express, session

Sorry, I don't know the best terminology to do what I am wanting to do.

I have several microservices that share a session secret. Once in a while, the session secret changes, and I will want to "refresh" the microservices with a new session secret.

In the case where, say, two of the microservices get the new secret but one of them doesn't, if the session cookie is signed with a new secret that the microservice does not have, then I can see the session cookie, but sessionID is not populated. This is how I determine if I need to refresh the session secret. So the microservice is able to grab the new secret and add it to the array of session secrets that was passed to express-session during initialization.

However, I was hoping that after this I could try to get the session again using the ID in the session cookie, and return the authenticated page to the user. The problem is, at this point express-session has already done its work, and there is no session present due to the fact that the ms saw a seemingly invalid signature. Currently my solution is to redirect back to the page after session secret is refreshed:

`res.redirect(req.originalUrl)`

This seems to be working, but is less than ideal. I was wondering if there is some way to tell express to go back to square 1, where it gets a session ID and verifies the signature, and then populates the session if it is present, without a redirect or anything, and once that is done continue to go through all the middleware as if this was a new request.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can just make a middleware before the express.session middleware. and put the logic there.

Comment: The only problem with this is that req.sessionID will not be populated at that point regardless, so I would hit that code path every single time. I only want to refresh the session secret if session cookie signature check is failed.